# Couldn't load plugin PRISM due an error when calling its classFactory() method in QGIS1.8 inWin8

Tags: qgis, python

[image]When I load a plugin in QGIS ,met some problems ：

I had tried copy other Python27's files to QGIS's Python 27 file but it still does't work.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Couldn't load plugin PRISM due an error when calling its classFactory() method

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 164, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\PRISM\__init__.py", line 25, in classFactory
    from prism import PRISM
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\PRISM\prism.py", line 15, in 
    import numpy
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in 
    import add_newdocs
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in 
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in 
    from type_check import *
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in 
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in 
    import multiarray
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 ���O���Ī� Win32 ���ε{���C

Python 版本:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS 版本:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, 6416f38

Python 路徑: ['C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/corbies/.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/corbies/.qgis//python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\Program Files\\Intergraph\\ERDAS IMAGINE 2014\\usr\\lib\\Win32Release\\python', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\qgis\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.2\\bin64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.2\\arcpy', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.2\\ArcToolbox\\Scripts', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

I think that the plugin designed for QGIS 1.8-1.99

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is not in the official repository.

You have to make sure that it will work with QGIS 1.8. Most plugins are designed to run with QGIS 2.0 and later only.

Comment: I think that the plugin designed for QGIS 1.8-1.99

Comment: `DLL load failed` might be a clue, but you better contact the author about it. Maybe some extra DLLs are needed, or the blanks in the folder are bad.